# How do I make a function that refers to specific cells on the same row or column as the cell I am coding?

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Basically, on my spreadsheet, I am needing to make a function for every cell where it adds the value of the cell on the previous (x-1) row to the value of the J cell on the same (x) row as the cell. In each of function, the J cell is also multiplied by the second cell of the selected cells column. All in all, the function should look something like this:

Ax=A(x-1)+J(x)*A2

I am wanting to input this into every cell so that it automatically selects cells from the proper column and row. I've tried a few different things, but I'm not used to Google sheets or spreadsheets in general and it seems there is no way to input a function where the computer can automatically select the row or column number of the cell you want depending on your cells location on the spreadsheet. Do I have to just keep inputting these functions manually?

I tried the column and row functions to see if they would let me create similar functions automatically over hundreds of cells, but they didn't do anything. All the functions do is tell you what row or column a specific cell is on a converts that location into a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something akin to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/156ieuLU5Kvof27F4Ih761Ex2VUugoNhKSis500rG1gU/edit?usp=sharing)?

Basically, you use the `$` modifier to make sure that as you drag the formula down, the `A2` value stays the same. The name for this is an "absolute reference"; you can do the same for the column part as well (i.e. `$A2` will keep the column value, but allows the row value to change, `$A$2` makes sure both will never change, regardless of where they go.

Comment: That is correct apparently.